# Most efficient way to shorten an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

How would one shorten an if statement if code is as below ?

```
$a = null;
$b = "foo";

if ((empty($a) && !empty($b)) || (!empty($a) && empty($b)) {}
```

Comment: Hard to say as we can't see where your data comes from - eg will it always be initiated (even if an empty value), will it never be a zero, etc.

Comment: Without any context. Only the situation I wrote about.

Comment: But you don't improve and make efficient PHP code with loose and vague changes. Otherwise what you have is already perfectly fine and there is no need to change it as you'll get no improvements. For example, if you always initialise these vars and 0 is a valid value, then you can omit the `empty()` check and let PHP convert to bool and do a truey check `if ((!$a && $b) || ($a && !$b))`. Specifics are required in order to satisfy something requiring specifics. But you have the answer anyway, `xor` is the way to go for this scenario :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$a = null;
$b = "foo";
if(empty($a) xor empty($b)){}
```

Answer (score 5):

The test seems to be checking that only 1 field contains a value, so you could check

```
$a = null;
$b = "foo";

if (empty($a) != empty($b)) {}
```

Comment: This will work, but personally I prefer the longer way to show intent more explicitly. Each to their own tho so +1 for valid solution

Comment: @James, it's a balance - some people sometimes look at the longer way and get confused with the extra conditions.  Sometimes a comment is better at showing intention than code.

Comment: There should be no need for comments in such simple code. I can easily see what you are doing, I guess I was just being pedantic dev :)